# RoR - Not getting confirmation email after registering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I tried adding a user confirmation email to my rails app. It worked fine, I enter my email and it says "Please check email for confirmation" but when I check my email/spam/junk, nothing is there. But if I login, it says "Please confirm email".

If I register again, it says email has been taken, but I checked my users using `rails c` and I cant find the email or user in ther.

My users_controller.rb

```
def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)

  if @user.save
    UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
    flash[:success] = "Please confirm email"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    flash[:error] = "Something went wrong..."
    render 'new'
  end
end

def confirm_email
user = User.find_by_confirm_token(params[:id])
if user
  user.email_activate
  flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App! Your email has been confirmed.
  Please sign in to continue."
  redirect_to signin_url
else
  flash[:error] = "Sorry. User does not exist"
  redirect_to root_url
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar_url)
end

end
```

My user.rb

```
require 'digest/md5'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

before_create :confirmation_token

before_validation :prep_email

    def create_avatar_url
        self.avatar_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest(self.email)}?s=50"
    end

has_secure_password

validates :name, presence: true
validates :username, uniqueness: true, presence: true
validates :email, uniqueness: true, presence: true, format: { with: /\A[\w.+-]+@([\w]+.)+\w+\z/ }

def email_activate
    self.email_confirmed = true
    self.confirm_token = nil
    save!(:validate => false)
end

private

def prep_email
    self.email = self.email.strip.downcase if self.email
end

def confirmation_token
  if self.confirm_token.blank?
      self.confirm_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64.to_s
  end
end
```

The sessions controller

```
  def create
user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
  if user.email_confirmed
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged in!"
else
    flash.now[:error] = 'Please activate your account by following the 
    instructions in the account confirmation email you received to proceed'
end


else
    flash.now[:error] = "Invalid user/pass"
  end
  end

  def destroy
    session.delete(:user_id)
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged out."
  end
```

The app/mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

default :from => "no-reply@domain.com"

def registration_confirmation(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => "#{user.name} <#{user.email}>", :subject => "Registration Confirmation")
end

end
```

And I also added a this in my routes file too

```
  resources :users do
member do
  get :confirm_email
end


 end
```

Also added a text.erb file in my app/views/user_mailer/registration_confirmation.text.erb

```
Hi <%= @user.name %>,

Thanks for registering! To confirm your registration click the URL below.

<%= confirm_email_user_url(@user.confirm_token) %>
```

I would really appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: Please show us your log : there is some lines with the mail content if it's sent.

Comment: please show us your development.rb file and smtp setting

Comment: @ForgetTheNorm Here are my development logs: http://pastebin.com/iEmtDVkX

Comment: @AmitSharma Here is the development.rb file http://pastebin.com/4NLHaP8Q

Comment: ok @moose So the mail is correcly sent. It's sent to `test@ucp.edu.pk`... No?

Comment: @moose I have checked your development.rb file. I think you have missed following.
`config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            '<username>',
  password:             '<password>',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }`

Comment: Please paste above code in your development.rb file and try to register.

Comment: @ForgetTheNorm Yes, but I can't see the mail in my inbox folder or spam.

Comment: @AmitSharma Sorry amit, its the same, I cant get the email in my inbox.

Comment: @moose can you show me what you have written in your development.rb file

Comment: @AmitSharma http://pastebin.com/tpfxMrUx

Comment: @moose have you changed the user_name, password with your real gmail email and password in smtp settings?

Comment: set `username` with your gmail account, and set `password` with your password gmail.

Comment: Your email won't be sent from your `localhost` if you are using `sendmail`. You can either change `development.rb` to use smtp settings or you can try `mailcatcher`.

Comment: @anonymousxxx I did add my username and password, didn't work.

Comment: @usmanali I added my smtp configuration in my development.rb file http://pastebin.com/tpfxMrUx

Comment: are you using a real account? I mean the gmail account.

Comment: @usmanali well, yes I am using my real gmail account.

Comment: if you are using sidekiq or delayed_job...you need to start it so that the workers pick up the jobs from the queue and process the request asynchronously.....

Comment: Come on guys, anyone?

Comment: is your confirmation email content apprearing on console after the registration.